# Why does only one argument appear in method decorator?

Tags: javascript, decorator, javascript-decorators

I'm having trouble with using method decorators in Javascript. Every source I have read on the subject, says I should be able to create them like this (note 3 arguments):

```
const debug = (target, name, descriptor) => {
    const method = descriptor.value;  descriptor.value = function(...args){
        console.log(`Calling ${name} with arguments: %o`, args);
        let result = method.apply(this, args);
        console.log(`result is %o`, result);
    };
}
```

And consume them like this:

```
    @debug
    message(obj) {
        return 'testing'
    }
```

However, when I run my code the decorator is only called with one argument, the property descriptor:

```
Object [Descriptor] {
  kind: 'method',
  key: 'message',
  placement: 'prototype',
  descriptor: {
    value: [Function: message],
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false
  }
}
undefined
undefined
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env"]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { "proposal": "minimal" }]
    ]
}
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are multiple different versions of the decorators proposal. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using this guy https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators.html and basically copy pasted their example.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who was tripped up by this: it looks like the examples from Babel docs use the legacy **stage 1** version instead of the current **stage 2** version. The issue was resolved by adding this to my `.babelrc`:

`["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]`

The stage 2 version is very different:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you!